# Error blockly on compilation

Tags: javascript, python, blockly

I'm trying to compile blockly,
I compile the file blockly_uncompressed.js well but the others compressed do not compile them. I do not know where the error may be.
This is a development that was left two years ago, and I have retaken it.

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "build.py", line 176, in run
  self.gen_core()
File "build.py", line 208, in gen_core
  self.do_compile(params, target_filename, filenames, "")
File "build.py", line 273, in do_compile
  json_data = json.loads(json_str)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
  raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I have never played blockly and I do not know where this can come from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `build.py` script used to use the closure compiler `http://` online compiler.  That compiler endpoint was deprecated. Try updating the URLs in script to `https`.

See the patch [here](https://github.com/google/blockly/commit/905d542ae55588440228402c066fe68e1eb9622b).

Comment: Thank you very much Anm, I had my project paralyzed by this error, and we did not know where to go, this error did not appear before leaving the project, we did not know that it also used an online compiler.

We understood that lowering the closure-library was enough to compile, or at least, it was before leaving the project